# Adjoining a root of $p$ to $F_p$ is etale?!

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I'm confused about etale extensions of $F_p$.
We know the etale extensions of a field are the products of separable finite field extensions. But if you take $F_p$ and adjoin a root of p this is separable and finite since $F_p$ is perfect. But this extension can't be etale since it is certainly badly ramified.

Comment: How is it badly ramified? It's true that $\mathbb{F}_p(T)(T^{\frac{1}{p}})$ is a ramified extension of $\mathbb{F}_p(T)$ but you're not in that case! In the case of a finite field you're fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ is $0$, and if you take $\mathbb{F}_p$ and adjoin a root of $0$ you just get $\mathbb{F}_p$ again.